# How do I include a custom class file from the terminal in Java?

Tags: java, terminal, compilation

The question seems simple and I used to know how to do this, but I've been looking everywhere to find how to do it again and the search seems fruitless so I thought I'd ask it myself. So I have two `.java` files in the same directory, `Main.java` and `Car.java`. I compile `Car.java` into `Car.class`. Then, I go to run the Main.java program using `java Main.java`, and then I'm given an error that the Car class wasn't found. I don't have any packages or anything like that. All of the files are in the same directory. I'm running a Linux machine and I'm using JDK 19.

Edit:

```
Main.java

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Car car1 = new Car("Chevrolet", "Monte Carlo SS", "Red", 2001, 5000.00F);
    Car car2 = new Car("Ford", "F150", "Black", 2018, 15000.00F);

    System.out.printf("Make of car1: %s\n", car1.make);
    System.out.printf("Model of car1: %s\n", car1.model);
    car1.drive();

    System.out.printf("Make of car2: %s\n", car2.make);
    System.out.printf("Price of car2: $%.2f\n", car2.price);
    car2.horn();
    car2.light();
    }
}
```

```
Car.java

public class Car {
    String make, model, color;
    int year;
    float price;

    public Car(String make, String model, String color, int year, float price) {
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.color = color;
    this.year = year;
    this.price = price;
    }

    public void driveCar() {
    System.out.println("You drive the car");
    }

    public void breakCar() {
    System.out.println("You break the car");
    }

    public void hornCar() {
    System.out.println("You honk the cars horn");
    }

    public void lightCar() {
    System.out.println("You turn on the cars lights");
    }
}
```

Comment: Before we go into further details, just try `javac *.java` followed by `java Main`

Comment: @g00se `javac *.java` produces errors that the methods that I try to call from the Car class cannot be found, so Main.java doesn't compile.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. If *the methods that I try to call from the Car class cannot be found* then it's *at least* the Car class that won't compile. So you need to fix those errors in that class first

Comment: @g00se The car class compiles. All of the methods I'm calling are public, and the class is public as well.

Comment: Please post the source of both in your question

Comment: @ g00se Just put them in.

Comment: You're calling methods from Main that don't exist

Comment: How do I delete a question ;_;

Comment: Why do you want to delete it? You're nearly there. If you get rid of the redundant string "Car" from the end of your *method names* in class `Car` and correct the typo "break" to *brake* then your code will work!

Comment: This just gets more and more embarrassing